# cget('image') method returning pyimage1 instead of the image name

Tags: python, widget, tkinter

I'm new to programming and I'm attempting to create an application using tkinter from python 3.3. In this application I'm using buttons containing images and I want to perform actions that depend on the kind of image that the buttons are containing. This is a simplified version of my program:

```
from tkinter import *
master=Tk()
c_black = PhotoImage(file="c_black.gif")
b=Button(master, image=c_black)
print(b.cget('image'))
master.mainloop()
```

Instead of

```
c_black
```

the console returns

```
pyimage1
```

And I have no idea why. I've been trying to figure it out for hours now. Perhaps there's a way to do it differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `cget()` you can only retrieve the property as a string, so you need to store the reference to the `PhotoImage` object:

```
b = Button(...)
b.image = c_black
print(b.image.cget('file'))
```