# Getting a PhotoImage object from a tkinter label

Tags: python, image, user-interface, tkinter

Is there any way to get a `tkinter.PhotoImage` object from a `tkinter.Label` instance? I know there's [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167754/cgetimage-method-returning-pyimage1-instead-of-the-image-name), which has a partially satisfying answer, but I really need to get a `PhotoImage` object:

```
>>> import tkinter as tk
>>>
>>> root = tk.Tk()
>>>
>>> image1 = tk.PhotoImage(file="img.gif")
>>> image2 = tk.PhotoImage(file="img.gif")
>>>
>>> label = tk.Label(root, image=image1)
>>> label._image_ref = image1
>>> label.cget("image") == image2
False
```

Is there perhaps a function which allows me to get an image object from a `pyimage` string? I.e. one obtained from `label.cget("image")`?

---

The answer is, [apparantly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47694173/8101215), you can't. The closest you can get to doing this is getting the image source (file or data) and checking (probably by hashing) whether or not the two images are the same. `tkinter.PhotoImage` does *not* implement an `__eq__`, so you can't just compare two images for equal data. Here's a final example which solves the problem (mostly):

```
import hashlib
import os
import tkinter as tk

_BUFFER_SIZE = 65536


def _read_buffered(filename):
    """Read bytes from a file, in chunks.
    Arguments:
    - filename: str: The name of the file to read from.
    Returns:
    - bytes: The file's contents.
    """
    contents = []
    with open(filename, "rb") as fd:
        while True:
            chunk = fd.read(_BUFFER_SIZE)
            if not chunk:
                break
            contents.append(chunk)
        return bytes().join(contents)


def displays_image(image_file, widget):
    """Check whether or not 'widget' displays 'image_file'.
    Reading an entire image from a file is computationally expensive!
    Note that this function will always return False if 'widget' is not mapped.
    This doesn't work for images that were initialized from bytes.
    Arguments:
    - image_file: str: The path to an image file.
    - widget: tk.Widget: A tkinter widget capable of displaying images.
    Returns:
    - bool: True if the image is being displayed, else False.
    """
    expected_hash = hashlib.sha256(_read_buffered(image_file)).hexdigest()
    if widget.winfo_ismapped():
        widget_file = widget.winfo_toplevel().call(
            widget.cget("image"), "cget", "-file"
        )
        if os.path.getsize(widget_file) != os.path.getsize(image_file):
            # Size differs, the contents can never be the same.
            return False
        image_hash = hashlib.sha256(
            _read_buffered(widget_file)
        ).hexdigest()
        return image_hash == expected_hash
```

Comment: You stored it as `label._image_ref`, don't you? Hence linked answer applies as `label._image_ref.cget('file')`. But why you claim that it's a partially satisfying? In your case equality always would be `False`, since it's a same thing as `image1 == image2` (`PhotoImage` doesn't have an `__eq__` method).

Comment: I'm writing a mock-up GUI testing library and I want a way to check whether an image is currently being displayed. I can't assume people will keep a reference to the image. I don't see why the `PhotoImage` `__eq__` implementation doesn't handle visual similarity, but that's a different issue.

Comment: `PhotoImage` objects don't define an `__eq__` method, so they inherit the default one, which means that doing `image1 == image2` is equivalent to `image1 is image2`, and so it will return False, since they aren't the same object, even though they contain identical image data.

Comment: Well, that's ridiculous, but I can *hopefully* get around that.

Comment: @Coal_, also, `> I can't assume people will keep a reference to the image.`. Why you can't? I can be wrong, but it's a must, because anyone should keep a reference.

Comment: Sure, but I don't have any idea *how* they keep a reference. It may just be a global reference. It may be saved as part of some other class, as an attribute (etc.). Even if I can assume it's an attribute of `label`, what's its name?

Comment: **1** "I can't assume people will keep a reference to the image." The docs clearly state that you generally need to keep a reference. It's not your fault if people don't read the docs. **2** Testing images for equal data is a relatively expensive operation. And Tkinter isn't an image processing library.

Comment: @Goyo That doesn't work at all, I don't know why you think it would (?)

Comment: @Coal_ Sorry, a mistake. Forget about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a `tkinter` is a wrapper over `tk` , so does `PhotoImage` in same fashion is a wrapper over [`image`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/image.htm). And it's clear that you can't just move backwards and create a `PhotoImage`, from that `image`.

But still, because you can execute tk commands and both `PhotoImage` and `image` have similar structure, your best bet would be something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

image1 = tk.PhotoImage(file="img.gif")
image2 = tk.PhotoImage(file="img.gif")

label = tk.Label(root, image=image1)
label._image_ref = image1

foo = root.call(label.cget('image'), 'cget', '-file')
bar = image2['file']
print('1st image:\t%s\n2nd image:\t%s\nEqual:\t%r' % (foo, bar, foo == bar))
```

- [tk image](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/image.htm)
- [tk photo](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/photo.htm)

Comment: I see where you're coming from. If I were to implement it like this, I'd probably open the file and hash the data to be sure their contents are the same. Then again, this is a pretty fragile solution (especially since the `PhotoImage` could also be initialized from image bytes). If I can't find any better solution I'll go with this. Thanks.

Comment: @Coal_, it's not a problem, since it's a wrapper, so `image` also can be initialized in that fashion. If it comes from bytes then check for `data` equality! Also, you can determine on the fly from which source it was initialized!

Comment: @Coal_, However, same files can be initialized by different paths, if so - it's a problem. But as @PM 2Ring mentioned that `tkinter isn't an image processing library` , so in this case you can't do much about it, even if you had a pair of `PhotoImage`s or pair of `image`s.

Comment: Could you point me to some docs on `root.call` or at least the `-file` flag? I can't seem to find that anywhere.

Comment: @Coal_, Sure, `call` is well described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28644054/what-does-the-tk-call-function-do-in-python-tkinter). And `-file` is an option, just like `image2['file']`. Follow a second link from my answer (or use a [shortcut](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/photo.htm#M8)).

Comment: Thanks a ton, I'm gonna go with this solution. I was looking at the [image command page](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/image.htm) by accident, so it made little sense to me.